# invert behavior of jQuery dropdown depending mediaquery

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I have a dropdown menu, here's the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo"><a>Menu1</a>
        <ul>
             <li>Cosas
             <li>Cosas
             <li>Cosas
        </ul>

     <li><a>Menu2</a>
        <ul>
             <li>Cosas
             <li>Cosas
             <li>Cosas
        </ul>

     <li><a>Menu3</a>
        <ul>
             <li>Cosas
             <li>Cosas
             <li>Cosas
        </ul>
</ul>
```

**The expected behavoir:** the menu must open when you click in any element. When you click another element, it must close the previous open element, and open the new one. But also, it looks different depending the resolution:

- Mobile: The `.foo` element must be close
- Desktop: The `.foo` item
  must be open, but keeping the open/close behavior.

This is the css:

```
ul li:nth-of-type(1) {background:pink}
ul li:nth-of-type(2) {background:gold}
ul li:nth-of-type(3) {background:aqua}
ul li ul li {background:white!important}
ul li ul {display:none}
ul li.foo ul {display:block}
ul li.on ul {display:block} 
ul li.foo.on ul {display:none}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    ul li.foo ul {display:none}
    ul li.foo.on ul {display:block}
}
```

I have a jQuery that efectively open/close the menu, but I can't make it to close the opened items:

```
$("ul li a").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('on');
$("li.on").not('$(this).parent()','.foo').removeClass('on');    

});
```

If I remove the second value in `.not()`, it closes properly, but when tried to open the second or third menu, the first one also opens.

Here's a fiddle if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/b7hkLrL4/3/

Comment: How about using jQuery UI Accordion for this: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @Xavjer Unfortunately it's not an option due to client requirements, and other behavior of the whole website.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, without accordion, i found your error, check this jsfiddle for the working solution
;)

http://jsfiddle.net/b7hkLrL4/4/

Problem was:

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo"><a>Menu1</a>
```

must be

```
<ul class="foo">
    <li><a>Menu1</a>
```

Edit:
And for your desire to have a different behaviour for desktop/mobile try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      //We are mobile
  } else {
      $(".foo li").first().toggleClass('on');
  }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thank, but we can't target the resolution by jQuery, because the mediaquery must start also in small resolution (desktop but heavily zoomed in, for example).

Comment: You have the jquery tag in your question, why do you set the tag when you are not allowed to use it then...

Comment: We can use jQuery. We can't use jQuery to targeting the device, because that isn't the only case.

Comment: How about this then to get the mobile devices: http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/jquery-and-css-media-queries